# Why command is NOT executed with PHP's system( )

Tags: apache

OK brief introduction:
I've got Apache running with php and mysql on a machine named 'Remote' (Windows 2000 Pro)

> Apache 2.0.64 - php 5.2.4 - mysql 4.0.21

and I want to execute this command:

> mysql --host=localhost --user=??? --password=??? <
>   C:\localhost\www_install.sql

The file `_install.sql` is simple:

```
USE my_database;
DROP TABLE my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id) );
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN datetime DATETIME;
```

... and it adds a few more columns this way.

So, when I connect to the 'Remote' using VNC, open command prompt (cmd), retype my command (typed earlier) everything is executed right, the table (my_table and contents) is gone and the table is recreated with rebuilt fresh columns.

But I don't want to mess with VNC, because it's not that easy to automate, I want to execute this command using php (via a webpage). 1st idea was to:

use the `system( )` command, but pasting my command to `system( )` function does not work :(

**Does anyone have an idea why?**

I've also tried the `exec( )` and `shell_exec( )` without positive result.

### Additional info:

- I want it done using php, bcs the client (user) I connect php with mysql has the rights and should be able to add/delete tables
- I find it useful to be able quickly reset a table to defaults
- I don't want to use VNC, bcs I'd have to install on each machine I connect to 'Remote' from (web browser is good enough)
- I really don't want reinstall or upgrade the apps to newer versions

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying to use exec() or system() when making mysql calls with PHP? PHP has functions to deal with this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "my_database");
$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE my_table");
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id) )");
```